# How to let resolveconf update DNS configuration when using NetworkManager

Tags: dns, networkmanager

I've recently noted that my `/etc/resolve.conf.head` and `/resolve.conf.tail` files were being ignored by NetworkManager DNS changes.

How to make use of them to add defaults nameserver configuration when using NM?

Answer (score 2):

Network Manager can use several tools to determine DNS. By default it replaces `/etc/resolv.conf` itself unless it is a symlink, thus ignoring `.head|.tail` files.

You should update NM configuration to use `resolveconf` util to update DNS configuration.

Change `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and add:

```
[main]
rc-manager=resolvconf
```

Then restart NM with `systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

See "man 5 NetworkManager.conf" for details.

Answer (score 0):

Linux will always use resolvconf for the DNS by default

You can just disable DNS handling on Network Manager with

/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-dns.conf

```
[main]
dns=none
```